# how do I call the asp postback of button inside datalist?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I get to the javascript postback event call for an asp button?

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button id="btnTest" runat="server" 
                    Text="button" OnClientClick="
            customAsyncConfirmDialog(function (isconfirmed)
            {
                if(isconfirmed)
                {
                    //call this buttons postback event
                    <%# Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(Container.FindControl("btnTest")))%>;
                }
            });return false;
            "/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Update: The customAsyncConfirmDialog is an asynchronous function that does not block the javascript to wait for a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to call the postback with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customConfirmDialog(sourceButton, callback) {
        setTimeout(function () { callback(sourceButton, true); }, 1);
        return false;
    }
</script>

<asp:DataList ID="dlTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(new PostBackOptions(Container.FindControl("btnTest")))%>;
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="neededfor__dopostbackgenerationforsomereason"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Button id="btnTest" runat="server" 
                    Text="button"
            OnClick="btnTest_OnClick"
                    OnClientClick="
                return customConfirmDialog(this,function (sourceButton, isconfirmed)
                {
                    if(isconfirmed)
                    {
                        //call this button's postback event
                        __doPostBack(sourceButton.name,'');
                    }
                }); 
            "/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I had to add a linkbutton to get `__doPostBack` to generate, not sure why the ASP:Button alone didn't trigger that. I still couldn't use the `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` in the `onClientClick` function.

Final note, you need to call `__doPostBack` with `sourceButton.name` rather that `sourceButton.id` to trigger the correct server side event.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do that. Just return true and the postback handler will be hit. Ex:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button id="btnTest" runat="server" 
                Text="button" OnClientClick="
        customConfirmDialog(function (isconfirmed)
        {
            return isconfirmed;                
        });
        "/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I'm having trouble accessing what I wrote earlier, but here's a quick example based on what you wrote in your other answer. You might need to change a few things but you should get the idea:

```
window.confirm = function(question, ok, cancel) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    ok = ok || 'OK'; //setup text for the confirmation
    cancel = cancel || 'Cancel';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#customMessage').text(question);
         var btnOk = $('#btnCustomOK');
         var btnCancel = $('#btnCustomCancel');
         btnOk.val(ok);
         btnCancel.val(cancel);

        btnOk.unbind("click"); //prevents chaining of events if multiple confirms are used
        btnCancel.unbind("click"); 
        btnOk.click(function() {
            $('#MyConfirm').hide();
            defer.resolve(true); //gets passed as isconfirmed=true
            return false; //prevent postback
        });

        btnCancel.click(function() {
            $('#MyConfirm').hide();
            defer.resolve(false);
            return false; //prevents postback
        });        

        $('#MyConfirm').show();                
        btnOk.focus();
    });
    return defer.promise();
}
```

Then to use:

```
<asp:Button id="btnTest" runat="server" Text="button"
  OnClientClick="confirm('My Message blah blah').then(//this runs after ok/cancel is clicked, thanks to defer.resolve() and defer.promise().
function(isConfirmed) {
 if (isConfirmed)
 __doPostBack(source.id,'');
}); return false;//return false here to prevent the initial postback from occurring"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

the 'source.id' part isn't exactly right, but the part with the promises should help you out.

Comment: yes, this works, except the customConfirmDialog is asynchronous, updating the question

Comment: So you're going to want promises. I actually implemented something very similar this year for this exact purpose. Overrode window.confirm to custom confirms, tied up with promises for handling the postbacks. Want me to post an example?

Comment: yes please, then I wouldn't have to deal with getting the postback call at all

Comment: some reason I couldn't tag @basher in the last comment

Comment: I'm writing you something up, visual studio crashed on me when I went to test it, though. Guess my computer can only handle 3 concurrent instances :(

Comment: Thank you! The .then is what I missed when I tried the deferred on my own. Also, to get the source.id to work you should be able to use `this.id`

Comment: what doesn't work? are you hitting the anonymous function inside of the `.then`?